# What's happening with reputation on meta sites?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, per-site-meta

I've noticed something odd happening on the [Drupal Answers meta site](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/).

The reputation shown in the top bar keeps jumping from:

[image: Image 2]

to:

[image: Image 1]

Am I (and my print screen function) just seeing things?

Comment: This is happening on the programmers meta as well.

Comment: No-repo on Movies' meta.

Comment: Probably to do with the different actual reputation one has on the main and meta sites and the new javascript polling code.

Comment: And print-screen is soooo WinXP

Comment: @TylerShads I'm on OSX Lion - I don't know what they call it? iPrintScreen? ;)

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on the same site. Do you have any extension, or UserScript that could interfere in some way?

Comment: @kiamlaluno - I noticed this only when I get upvotes on the meta site.

Comment: @Oded That is probably why I don't notice the behavior.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't have any SE specific extensions/UserScripts, no. I do have a few installed (YSlow/Adblock/some SEO tools), but nothing I imagine would interfere

Comment: @Clive It is probably related with receiving votes on the meta site, as Oded said. I don't recall seeing any change in the reported reputation, even if one of my answers have been up-voted, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Realtime reputation updates will be disabled on child metas since you can't really earn reputation on these sites.  This will be in the next deploy.