# Do I have reputation on meta?

Tags: discussion, bug, stack-overflow, reputation, per-site-meta

This is weird. On [meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com) I seem to have my own reputation, different from my Stack Overflow reputation. Yet, according to [the FAQs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), there is no reputation on *any* meta site (other than this one, Stack Exchange Meta) As stated:

> *Votes on meta **do not** affect your **reputation***; your meta reputation is **the same** as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

So I shouldn't have any reputation on meta. *However* **I do**, along with everybody else.

---

### How to see your meta reputation in 3 easy steps (with [Ethan K](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/440822/ethan-k))

1. Click on this button:

   [image: community nav button]
2. Then add *any meta site that is not this one* to the `YOUR COMMUNITIES` section with the edit button next to it. You may want to add the main site as well if it is not already there (for ease of seeing the <del>bug</del> *feature*, not required)
3. Profit!

---

The <del>problem</del> *feature* will become visible - your meta account has a reputation of its own!

[image: 133 on meta, 488 on main???]
<sup>See it without markup on it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvmmU.png).</sup>

If you are wondering what is going on here, this is what happened: A Stack Overflow employee saw [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297639/why-doesnt-meta-stack-overflow-have-real-reputation) (animuson?) and even though [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) is *shown*, the Stack Overflow team secretly added it (steps to trigger it shown above) and it took 3 years and 6 months for someone (me!) to find it. Somebody (a moderator) should *really* edit that post to [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

<del>**Or it could be a bug.**</del> *Naw.*

The Stack Overflow Team should either (#1) Remove this value altogether *or* (#2) Add it as a useless value to everybody's profile as well so more people can enjoy it (for the coolness factor only, no real effect). Personally, I like the idea of #2 so you can see what your rep ***would be*** on meta (no purpose other than looking cool, mind you). You can suggest your opinion in the comments/an answer if you like.

But this isn't a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report, so don't downvote this if you don't like my opinion on how Stack Overflow should handle this.

Anyway, can we fix this bug?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that. Sorry. Sadly, nobody answered that question either. :(

Comment: Re *"there is no reputation on any meta site."*: How did you arrive at that conclusion? It says *"Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Stack Overflow (synchronized hourly)"*

Comment: 2012-04-28: From *[What's happening with reputation on meta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130618)*:  *"Realtime reputation updates will be disabled on child metas since you can't really earn reputation on these sites. This will be in the next deploy."*

Comment: What do you mean by *"have reputation on meta"*? Separate reputation on meta and the main site (subject to synchronisation problems)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen This is not a synchronization problem. It has gone on for days and the number is what my reputation *would be* if you had separate reputation on meta.